# jQuery action in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to translate this Prototype snippet to jQuery:

```
div id="do_bookmark" <%= style_for_do_bookmark @gigapan %> >
    <%= link_to_remote "Add to Favorites",
        :url => { :controller => "bookmarks", 
                  :action => "create", 
                  :user_id => current_app_user.id, 
                  :bookmarked_type => @photo.class.to_s, 
                  :bookmarked_id => @photo.id },
        :method => 'post'
    %>
</div>
```

What would be the best way to do this to capture the controller, action,etc in the URL?

Comment: Are you trying to do this on rails 3? because there's no `link_to_remote` there anymore...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Rails 3` you can do this by

```
<%=
  link_to 'add to favorites',{
    :controller=> 'bookmarks',
    :action => 'create',
    :user_id => current_app_user.id,
    :bookmarked_type  => @photo.class.to_s,
    :bookmarked_id => @photo.id
  },
  :remote=>true
%>
```

and that would do the remote link for you.

but if you wan to do this with `jQuery` you can do a function like this:

```
function addToFavorites(photoId,photoClass){
  $.ajax({
    url:"<%=
       url_for(
         :controller=> 'bookmarks',
         :action => 'create',
         :user_id => current_app_user.id
       )%>",
       data: "bookmarked_id="+photoId+"&bookmarked_type="+photoClass,
       dataType: "script"
  });
}
```

and you can call the function from a link

```
<a href="#" onclick="addToFavorites(<%=@photo.id%>,<%=@photo.class%>); return false">
  Add To Favorites
</a>
```

For extra documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ (jQuery Ajax())

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html (Rails URL Helpers)

Comment: ), on line 8 of addToFavorites seems to be throwing an error.  I am using Rails 2.  Would the function syntax change?

Comment: @ansible just updated the answer, didn't close the rails tag where it should be closed.